# Remote Desktop Active X Control doesnt connect

Tags: c#, windows-10, rdp

I'm trying to write a c# winform that uses the [Remote Desktop Active X Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/TermServ/remote-desktop-web-connection-reference).  But I'm failing to connect to my Testserver. (To which I can connect via mstsc and the same username/password)

It seams that the Control is stuck in the Connecting state as this is the only event that fires and the Control remains white.

I've added this control vom the COM Components:
[Component Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ahLZ.png)

My code is:

```
private void Connect()
    {
        rdpClient.Server = "10.0.0.13";
        rdpClient.UserName = "test";
        rdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = "test";

        rdpClient.OnConnecting += RdpClientOnOnConnecting;
        rdpClient.OnConnected += RdpClientOnOnConnected;
        rdpClient.OnWarning += RdpClientOnOnWarning;
        rdpClient.OnFatalError += RdpClientOnOnFatalError;

        rdpClient.Connect();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I'm using a Windows 10 PC for development if that changes anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also set the property of Credential support . Add this line after setting the clear passowrd

```
 rdpClient.AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
```

So your full code should look like this

```
private void Connect()
{
    rdpClient.Server = "10.0.0.13";
    rdpClient.UserName = "test";
    rdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = "test";
    rdpClient.AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true;

    rdpClient.OnConnecting += RdpClientOnOnConnecting;
    rdpClient.OnConnected += RdpClientOnOnConnected;
    rdpClient.OnWarning += RdpClientOnOnWarning;
    rdpClient.OnFatalError += RdpClientOnOnFatalError;

    rdpClient.Connect();
}
```